# Larvel blade not loading all images from pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-pagination

I have a Projects model which it fields includes a "path". This path is the file name of a project image.

While in my controller I get the Project models by paginating it

```
$projects = Project::pagnate(2)
```

and I return the view

```
return view('gallery', ['projects' => $projects])
```

Now in the blade I loop through the results and and get the path value like so

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<img src = {{'uploads' ./ .$project->path}}/>
endforeach
```

the first two images can be seen, but on the 2nd, 3rd ..... Nth pages, some times I have to reload the page for the images to load properly.

What could be the issue here, and how do I solve this.

Comment: How are you navigating to the other pages?

Comment: try changing <img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$project->path)}}"/>

Comment: I am navigating to other pages using the paginate links() method

Comment: I experience the same issue with  <img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$project->path)}}"/>